# How to find total number of triangle formed by four lines.

Tags: geometry

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYvPj.png)

there are four lines in the plane and the endpoints is given (x1,y1) (x2,y2) for the first line and same for the other lines, how to calculate the total number of triangles formed by those lines?

my approach:-

i am calculating the slopes for each line by (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) and then counting the number of lines that have different slopes and then I am applying the formula N(N-1)/2 for calculating the total number of triangles formed by those lines.

Comment: Are these lines or line segments? If segments, do the vertices of the triangles have to be endpoints of the segments? Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: Just posting a screenshot of a problem without any thoughts of your own will probably not attract helpers. Please include your thoughts on the problem, what you have tried, why you are trying to solve it in the first place etc.